# specify a custom equals and hash functions for containers in Java

Tags: java, containers

I have a list of things with many fields, and I'd like to find duplicates in several of these fields.

For example:

```
class Person {
    String givenName, surName, country, city, street;
    int id;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (!(other instanceof Person)) return false;
        return ((Person)other).id == id;
    }
    @Override
    public hashCode() { return id; }
}
```

Converting the list into a set, would only find duplicate entries of the same person - but is there a way to create a custom Set that would let me filter out duplicates according to any other of the fields?

In C++, you'd give the container a functional at construction time (or use std algorithms with a functional) which determined the order\equality of the objects - is there such a solution for Java, or do I have to write the algorithm by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom hash algorithm is not supported in current java.util classes. But you can use other hash containers. E.g [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (previous GS Collections) It has HashingStrategy interface.

PS
thanks to @Mr.WorshipMe comment

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Thanks! Java 9 should include these as standard.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible, because Java 9 features list is frozen already. And it does not include custom hashing.

Comment: Java 10, then... :( I wonder how they explain the lack of support for functionals in their core algorithms and containers, seems like a huge oversight on their part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `TreeSet<Person>` and pass to it a `Comparator<Person>` that determines both the order of the elements and the uniqueness of elements.

If the `compare` method of your `Comparator<Person>` returns 0 for two `Person` instances, your `TreeSet<Person>` will consider them to be the same `Person`.

Note that for each criteria by which you wish to determine the equality of `Person` objects, you'll have to create a separate `TreeSet<Person>` instance using a different `Comparator<Person>`.

Comment: So there's no way to have a custom contained with O(1) insertions and deletions? This makes the finding of duplicates O(nlog(n)) instead of O(n)...

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe Well, you could sub-class your `Person` class and override `equals` and `hashCode` to support the custom equality criteria, but that would require converting your `Person` instances to instances of the sub-class.

Comment: apart from making me subclass for each property, there's the problem of no down-casting allowed in Java...